# How to delete specific cron using php

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I want to create and remove cronjobs using php. I am using

`exec('echo -e "`crontab -l`\n30 9 29 7 * curl http://myurl/send-cron" | crontab -');`

this code to create cron and right now it's working good but I also want to delete specific cron how can i do this and please tell me is this right way to create cron using php

Comment: I wouldn't use PHP at all for this, but as you already are using it, one choice is to output crons into a file with crontab -l > myfile, then open that file, start parsing it, look for similarities over the line you want to remove (e.g. script name), remove that line, build the file up again and send command crontab myfile. Sloppy, but it'll work.

Comment: Please explain me bit more about this process currently I am not using any file to stroe any thing I just run this line of code and cron is created in to my cpanel and works at the time I pass in this

Comment: I would avoid this process all together. Bad bad mistake using exec, plus for you to edit the cronjobs u have to ask, what permission level Is your web server user running at? Please don't say root

Comment: The process would be to first send a command "crontab -l > myfile", which stores the crontab output into file named myfile. After that, you can open the file "myfile" with fopen inside PHP, go through the file line by line, save the lines you don't care about, but when you find the line which you want to remove (by using strpos for example), you just ignore that line and go on. After the file is done reading, you can write the lines you saved into a new file and send the command ("crontab mynewcron") which will overwrite crontab with the file you just created, hence removing the task from it.

Comment: did you ever get this working??